# Edittext Move Next to Item of Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I created a recycler view in which one is text view and other is edit text where data is added at runtime so I want to do that when I click of a keyboard next button then it moves to next edit text item issue is when I do it move to text view instead of edit text and so on... as shown in below image. what can I do that this is going through as my requirement? I tried all answers of s.o.f but failed.

here is my adapter code where the item is shown.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    StudentMarks subject = subjectList.get(position);
    holder.subjectName.setText(subject.getStudentsName());
    holder.subjectId.setText(Collections.singletonList(subject.getStudentsId()).toString());
    holder.subjectMarks.setText(subject.getStudentMarks());
    if (!idStudent.contains(subject.getStudentsId())) {
        idStudent.add(subject.getStudentsId());}

    holder.subjectMarks.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            subjectList.get(position).setStudentMarks(holder.subjectMarks.getText().toString());
            try {
                String st_id = subjectList.get(position).getStudentsId();
                for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++) {
                    if (id.get(i).equals(st_id)) {
                        id.remove(subjectList.get(position).getStudentsId());
                        value.remove(i);
                    }}
                id.add(subjectList.get(position).getStudentsId());
                value.add(holder.subjectMarks.getText().toString().trim());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (idStudent.toArray().length != id.toArray().length) {
                listListener.onArrayListListener(id, value, position, "Please Enter Student Marks First");
            } else {
                listListener.onArrayListListener(id, value, position, "Student Marks Submitted");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
}
```

here is xml code

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_student_category"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/add_marks_category"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/add_student_List"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:hint="@string/student_name"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:textColor="@color/greenish_shade"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
        tools:ignore="Deprecated,LabelFor" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_marks_category"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/add_student_category"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/add_student_category"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/add_student_category">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/add_exam_marks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/obtain_marks"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/greenish_shade"
        android:textColorHint="@color/greenish_shade"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:background="@color/light_black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/add_student_category" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/student_idss"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `android:inputType="text"` in editText in xml file

if you are adding dynamic edittexts then you can do it like this

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

refere this [site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType) where you can found various input types according to your need like for password(this will hide the typed text), numbers(numbered keyboard),etc

Comment: you dont understand what issue is , the issue is when i click next button of keyboard it move to textview name field instead of next obtn marks edittext i want to do when i click next it move next edittext obtn marks field not name textview field

Comment: i update my question with xml kindly check it

Comment: change first edittext inputType="text" and set textview visibility to GONE ok?? are you using recyclerview to display this edittext multiple times ??

Comment: yes i am using recyclerview i use input type number because i want to enter only number other than,visibility gone  not possible in recyclerview

Comment: you edited inputType="text" in first edittext ??

Comment: i add inputType="number"

Comment: you set android:inputType="none" i want you to just change it to android:inputType="text" in first edittext

Comment: inputtype none is student name field which is left side of list and right side of edittext is set inputtype number

Comment: i know just do what i said, try it bro who know if it works.

Comment: the student name i dont want to make edit because it come from server.

Comment: so you just want to pass cursor between this obtMarks edittext right ??

Answer (score 0):

you can add `android:maxLines="1" & android:inputType="text"` to your EditText. It will surely work.